# $A$ is a finite $\implies$ $f(A)$ is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Please check my proof! I'm very happy to receive any suggestion to make my proof better!

Theorem:

> Suppose that $A$ is a finite and that $f$ is a mapping from $A$ to $B$. Then $f(A)$ is finite.

Proof:

> Since $A$ is finite, there exists a bijection $g:I_n \to A$.
>
> $f:A \to f(A)$ is surjective $\wedge g:I_n \to A$ is bijective $\implies f \circ g:I_n \to f(A)$ is surjective.
>
> Let $h:f(A) \to  I_n$ such that $h(x)=\min(f \circ g)^{-1}\{x\}$, then $h:f(A) \to h(f(A))$ is bijective and $h(f(A)) \subseteq I_n$. Thus $f(A)$ is finite.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks good to me.  I think the third line could be expressed in a cleaner way.

Comment: @QthePlatypus, please rewrite that part for clarity!

Comment: You appear to be using the fact that a subset of an $I_n$ is equipotent to an $I_m$. This surely requires a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you have a surjection from $A$ to $B$, it follows that $\lvert B\rvert\le\lvert A\rvert$.  The proof uses the axiom of choice...

See the [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).

Comment: Thank you for your approach, but it would be better for me not to appeal to axiom of choice :) Also, is my proof fine?

Comment: @DungLe sure.  I guess you probably don't have to:   just use the definition of a function,  as you have essentially done...

Comment: Any time the domain of the surjection is well-ordered the proof *does not use the axiom of choice*. In particular when the domain is finite.